# Use excel vba to Input value on an .asp page

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm writing VBA code in Excel to generate various reports.
Once it's done I would really like (and I would be looked at like a hero by my fellow co-worker) to input my results directly on our corporate intranet.

So I've started educating myself on how to use VBA to interact with Internet Explorer.  I know get the basics so I can do cool  stuff  (but unusefull in this case ) like loading a web site.  But when I try to input values in a text box on this page on the Intranet, I can't go any where.

I'm suspecting that the problem is caused by the fact that the adress I'm accessing is ending with .asp  extension.

Here's the code I'm using below 
Beware that I will most probably have other questions following this first one.  You might just become my new-web-geek-bestfrient ;-)

```
Sub interaction()
  'Variables declaration

  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
  Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
  Dim ZoneMotsClés As HTMLInputElement
                'page to be loaded, it's on a corporate intranet
  IE.navigate "http://intranet.cima.ca/fr/application/paq/projets/index.asp"
  IE.Visible = True

  Do    ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
  Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  Set IEDoc = IE.document

  'this is the text zone that I'm trying to input value into
  Set ZoneMotsClés = IEDoc.getElementById("txtMotCle")    

  'this is where it crashes.  At this point I'm only trying to enter a project number into  
  'the "txtMotCle" 'text zone

  ZoneMotsClés.Value = "Q141763B" 
  '.....

  Set IE = Nothing
  Set IEDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

So at this point (when I try to input the value in the text box I get a:
    error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

and here's the html code of the section on the page I'm trying to write in.

```
<INPUT onfocus="javascript:document.frmMyForm.TypeRecherche.value='simple';"
 style="FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana" maxLength=250 size=60 name=txtMotCle>
```

This time I tried the suggestions of the 2 contributors (Tx Jeeped and Tim Williams) but still getting the same error 91.

Now I tried that modification (tx SeardAndResQ)

```
    'this is the text zone that I'm trying to input into
   'Set ZoneMotsClés = IEDoc.all("txtMotCle")
   ID = "txtMotCle"
   Set ZoneMotsClés = IEDoc.getElementById(ID)

   'this is where it crashes.  At this point I'm only trying to enter a project number into the "txtMotCle"
   'text zone
   ZoneMotsClés.Value = "Q141763B"
```

Same result.  I'm not sure I made it the way @searchAndResQ meant it

Comment: What is `txtMotCle`? Is it the id of an input tag? If it is, then change the variable assignment above the crash to `Set ZoneMotsClés = IEDoc.getElementById("txtMotCle")` and then you can set the input value with `ZoneMotsClés.Value = "Q141763B"`.

Comment: Typically it doesn't make any difference what the extension at the end of the URL is - essentially all any URL does is deliver a page of HTML to the browser.  Whether it's a static page (.html) or dynamic (.asp, .jsp, etc) doesn't matter from the browser perspective.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I tried the suggestion from Jeeped but I still get that same error 91 message.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You have given the name for the input, add an id to it.  `id="txtMotCle"`

Comment: Could you look at the end of my question please?  I've tried it but still no luck...

Comment: `getElementById` only works if the element you want has a matching **id** attribute - it doesn't work on `name`.  Maybe try`IEDoc.frmMyForm.txtMotCle.value = "Q141763B"`

Comment: This : `<INPUT onfocus="javascript:document.frmMyForm.TypeRecherche.value='simple';"
 style="FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana" maxLength=250 size=60 name=txtMotCle>` should be changed to : `<INPUT onfocus="javascript:document.frmMyForm.TypeRecherche.value='simple';"
 style="FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana" maxLength=250 size=60 name=txtMotCle id="txtMotCle">`

Comment: BTW i did try your code; only thing that was missing was the `id` attribute in your html.

Comment: You should make the change in the .asp page. Add an id attribute to the input `<INPUT onfocus="javascript:document.frmMyForm.TypeRecherche.value='simple';" style="FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana" maxLength=250 size=60 name="txtMotCle" id="txtMotCle">`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - I don't think the OP owns the page...

Comment: @TimWilliams  oh ok. Then accessing it like `IEDoc.frmMyForm.txtMotCle.value = "Q141763B"`, as you noted, might work

Comment: You could try using [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)    `Set ZoneMotsClés = IEDoc.getElementsByName("txtMotCle")(0)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, tx for your efforts guys.  I the    IEDoc.frmMyForm...  suggestion.  It now ends up with a Run time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property of method"  Any ideas why I now get this?  Also you're right I don't own the page and the "Intranet master" isn't really open to the idea of me inputing automatic data on his form, so I can't expect much help from him.  So if you have any other ideas and are still willing to help, feel free to do so.  Maybe it's just not possible...